# Issues with Accessing Superclass Properties (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, overloading

I am running into an issue where it seems to be ignoring functions I try to overload.

I have a class called `Projectile` that extends the `Entity` class. Projectile is passed an array of MovieClips to compare collision against. If it collides with one of those array elements, `collidingWith` is set to that object. The `onCollision()`function is then called to resolve what should happen to the colliding object.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip{
    ...
    for(var i in projectileArray){
         projectileArray[i].update();
    }
    ...
}

public class Entity extends MovieClip{
        protected var canCollideWith:Array; //Array of objects to test collision against
        protected var collidingWith:Object; //Object this projectile collided with
        ...
        protected function update(){
             this.checkCollision()
        }

        protected function checkCollision(){
             for(var in canCollideWith){
                   if (image.hitTestObject(canCollideWith[i])){
                          collidingWith = canCollideWith[i];
                          this.onCollision();
                   }
             }
        }

        protected function onCollision(){
             //To be overriden by child classes
             trace("Entity onCollision");
        }

}

public class Projectile extends Entity{
        public function Projectile(...){
             super.(...);
        }

        override protected function onCollision(){
             trace("Projectile onCollision");
        }
}
```

Based on trace statements I tried, I am able to overload `Entity.update()` and `Entity.checkCollision`, it will not let me override `Entity.onCollision()`. It will only ever go to the `onCollision` function of Projectile's superclass (Entity).

Further, when I attempt to access `collidedWith` from within any Projectile function, it remains at its default value, and is not sharing the value it should be set to from within `Entity.checkCollision()`.

Am I missing something? Is there some OOP aspect I am overlooking?

Thanks in advance,

Glen

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out the problem. Projectiles can collide with Mortals, which are both subclasses of Entity. The trace statements for collision were being called from within the Mortal class, not Projectile, hence why the override did not appear to work.